# SQL Full text match value is returning only Boolean (1 or 0) for matched items

Tags: mysql, match, full-text-search

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    g.*,
        (
            MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
    AS MatchValue,
    p.id AS platformid,
    p.alias AS PlatformAlias,
    p.name,
    p.icon
FROM
    games AS g,
    platforms AS p
WHERE
    (
        (
            MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
        OR
        (
            MATCH (g.Alternates) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.Alternates SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
    )

AND g.Platform = p.id
ORDER BY MatchValue DESC
```

Which returns a correct set of results when matching against a FullText Index, however the "MatchValue" that is reported is of a Boolean nature (0 or 1) only.

If I remove line 5 of the statement:

```
OR g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
```

I get decent match values ranging from say around 5.23 to 15.56, but I lose some functionality when matching against "Alternates".

I'm not brilliant with SQL and it has taken me several days to get it functioning this much...

Is there any way to get lines 5 and 6 to return a non boolean match value so that my results are properly ordered?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: How do you expect to determine relevance values for `g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'` (or, essentially, `SOUNDEX(g.GameTitle)`) that meaningfully relate to the relevance values returned by `MATCH` and can be sorted among them?

Comment: It seems I had incorrectly assumed that SOUNDEX returned a relevance value, maybe I was confusing it with something else... thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `'ABC' OR (3 > 2)` you are asking for a `BOOL` result. You cannot either get a string or a boolean. In the above case, the string `'abc'` translates to boolean **0**, since it does not represent a number.

Since it does not make much sense in `OR`ing a string and a boolean, I would separate the two:

```
SELECT
    g.*,
        (
            MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
    AS MatchResultBoolean,
    MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty') AS MatchText,
    p.id AS platformid,
    p.alias AS PlatformAlias,
    p.name,
    p.icon
FROM
    games AS g,
    platforms AS p
WHERE
    (
        (
            MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
        OR
        (
            MATCH (g.Alternates) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.Alternates SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
    )

AND g.Platform = p.id
ORDER BY MatchValue DESC
```

Note the change:

```
        (
            MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty')
            OR g.GameTitle SOUNDS LIKE 'call of duty'
        )
    AS MatchResultBoolean,
    MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('call of duty') AS MatchText,
```

This way you get it both ways: one time you get the boolean value, in a nother column you get the (possible) match.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining this to me, it makes more sense your way.
I guess if I wanted to be able to include both types of matches in my application and sort this mixed set by relevance I could take the results from the above query that you have provided, stick them all into a PHP array (or equivalent) and perform a sort on them there based from the initial search string...
Which while we're on the subject of, I don't suppose you know of a library/script or some resources which could accomplish this type of relevance sorting in php?
Thanks again for the help! ;)

Comment: Ii might be an overstretch, but [sphinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is a very capable search engine. This considerably complicates stuff for you, though, I think.